# React native create elements align in circle dynamically

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

Here is what I want to achive:

[image: Here is what I want to achive]

Hi, I am trying to do an element that has an image center in the middle and then around it icons align in a circle, and where it would align depending on how many elements are.
Here is my code now: https://snack.expo.io/@dvidd/moody-yogurt

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please make sure that you put all the necessary codes inside the question. Do not use links as they might not be available in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I see you use absolute positions to manually hard code where the icons should go. You would need to provide a position variable that is calculated, instead.

If you want to create a component that dynamically positions your icons around your profile icon, you have to consider a couple of things:

1. Your profile picture to be the 'origin' for your component. Maybe request this profile icon as a prop.
2. Create a prop that reads the data for the surrounding icons.
3. Consider how icons should be placed around the circle. If there is no data provided, should anything be rendered? If there's one icon, where should that be placed? What about two icons? And so on... Should there be a max number of icons? Should the icons be resized if there are too many icons? Should you consider adding in lazy loading?

Suggestions:
I would personally avoid using percentages for positioning components relative to one another. Perhaps consider using flexbox or css grid. Create an outermost container holding two subcomponents. The components should be of the same dimensions, place the profile icon in the center of the first inner component. The latter component should hold your other icons. Style the latter component position absolute after placing the icons in their respective locations. Effectively layering your components. Make sure the latter component has a higher z-index since it should be stacked on top.

You could possibly get positions for your icons relative to the parent div containing the icons using knowledge of trigonometric functions and solve this problem mathematically.